How can I get my gets(name) function to work after startgame()?
I've been working at this problem for a few hours now but can't seem to get around this. I believe it might be due to the scanf in startgame() creating a new line character after it's finished, but none of the methods I've read about online to sidestep this issue have worked. Could I get some help understanding and solving this issue?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int startgame();

int main(){
    char name[256];
    int dexterity, endurance, strength, intelligence, health = 0;
    int endingtokens = 0;
    
    startgame();

    gets(name);

    return 0;
}

int startgame(){
    char decision [100];

    do{
        printf("Welcome to 'A Week in Basilisk'. Type 'start' to continue.\n");
        scanf("%s", decision);

            if(strcmp(decision, "start") == 0){
                printf("starting...");
            }

            else if (strcmp(decision, "quit") == 0){
                printf("quiting...");
                exit(0);
            }

    }

    while(strcmp(decision, "start") != 0);

    return 0; 
}

I've tried replacing the scanf with fgets, adding spaces to scanf and all if statement conditions, and adding \n to scanf/all if statement conditions.

You should not be using gets() anymore. It has been removed from the language. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used

You never say what the problem is.

What is the purpose of the line gets(name);? Do you want the program to wait for the user to press the ENTER key before the program terminates? Or is there some other reason? Please [edit] the question to clarify this.

OT: Of the variables in the comma separated definition, only health is initialised. The rest will contain uninitialised values. Comment: Don't get ahead of yourself! Get ONE function/facility working (and tested) before typing all the wonderous OTHER things that the program is to do. (Add the "characteristics" in a comment, if necessary, to avoid forgetting about them. They are only "noise" to the compiler at this point in development.)

I think your problem is scanf() leaves the newline in the input buffer.  But you should not be using gets() even so.

Related/possible duplicate: fgets doesn't work after scanf

The line
scanf("%s", decision);

will not read an entire line of input. It will read at most a single word of input, which means that it will leave at least the newline character at the end of the line inside the input buffer. This means that the line
gets(name);

will not wait for user input, but will read the remainder of the line that scanf left in the input buffer, including the newline character, and return immediately.
If you don't want that, then you can discard the remainder of the line that scanf left in the input buffer, by running the following code immediately before calling the gets function:
int c;
while ( (c=getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF )
    ;

This loop will read and discard one character at a time until it has read and discarded the newline character.
However, in your case, it would probably be better not to use scanf in the first place, but to instead always read a whole line of input at once. That way, you won't have the problem of leftover input in the input buffer. In order to read a whole line of input at once, I recommend that you change the line
scanf("%s", decision);

to:
fgets( decision, sizeof decision, stdin );
decision[ strcspn( decision, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

Because fgets writes the newline character into the array decision, I added the second line of code to remove it, by overwriting it with a null character. If there is no newline character, then the second line of code will overwrite the null character with another null character, which is harmless.
